# Export and import button for all the data tables from database

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin

I have a window form that have two buttons one for Export all the data tables in the mysql database  & the other one for import all the data tables in case i lost them. So How i will can doing that's  ??

Any one can help me with source code, I'm using phpmyadmin with C#

Thanks

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just want to get backup to my content for  all the tables in my database. and save it in my external hard. In case happen damage or format the computer i will not loss the data in the database. Cuz i get backup to all my data base data. So i just need to import this file again the my program.... (i.e i just want to export the configuration for database as file on external hard then import this file when i need it). I hope this will be clear. I'm grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code it into c# , phpMyAdmin got Export and Import in it's tools you can find it in the main screen right after you login .

If you insist on making it in a c# code , try to deal with the database as if it's a file , which means that you will make your export button go to the database directory and copy the database file to somewhere else or send it wherever !

**Note**

Consider reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

***Edit***

**How to Export Db :**

1. Log in to the phpMyAdmin instance on the source server.
2. Click the Export tab
3. From the database drop-down (left navigation), select the type of your database.
4. Choose between a Quick or a Custom export. The Quick method should work most of the time, though if you need to get more granular with your export options, click Custom
5. Select the format from the Format drop-down
6. Click the Go button.
7. Save the file (which, by default, should be named *.sql

Comment: So how i will make my export button go to the database directory and copy the database file to somewhere else or send it wherever ?

Comment: I Edited my Answer providing you with the steps.